# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' ​

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm trying to loop over columns to find a 0 in a specific cell (eg 'Users 0') in all columns of the df and replace the cell with null.

I tried running this :

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[sa[col].str.contains('0'), col] = ''
```

But it gives me 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
​

Comment: What is `sa[col]`? The error is telling you that `str` is not a member of `sa[col]`. That's a good place to start looking at what might be going on

Comment: What is `sa` here?

Comment: Why do you use `df` as a source dataframe but `sa` as a filter dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, sa is my actual dataframe, I was keeping it 'df' for the purpose of alias. It's sa.loc[sa[col] in my notebook anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your dataframe has multiple columns with the same name.  I can recreate this error by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['0','1','2'],['2','4','5']],columns = ['a','b','b'])
for c in df.columns:
    print(df[c].str.replace("1",""))
```

The problem is that once you get to the repeated column name (in my example, when `c == 'b'`), then `df[c]` is actually a dataframe with 2 cols and .str is not available.

So if this is your issue, find the columns with the same name and give them unique names.

Also, as mentioned by @JonClements it isn't necessary to loop over the columns at all, you can just do `df = df.replace('.*0.*', '', regex=True)`

Comment: The cell doesn't contain just '0', it contains strings like 'users 0', 'accounts 0'. I want to replace the entire cell with NaN where there's any occurrence of '0' within that string. Will replace do that?
Thanks

Comment: @user14318465 does `DataFrame.replace` work in your case, eg: `df.replace('.*0.*', '', regex=True)`

Comment: @JonClements I tried:
for col in df.columns:
    df.replace('.*0.*', '', regex=True)
But it didn't work :(

Comment: You don't want to loop... just literally `df.replace('.*0.*', '', regex=True)` which should give you a new DF back as you desire?

Comment: I was just using replace as an example of a string operation, not to solve your whole problem.  Did deduplicating the columns at least get rid of the `.str` error?